# Nativescript ios build fails with Error 65

Tags: nativescript

I've run into an issue where suddenly my ios build will no longer build. It seems to have happened out of no-where.

I get this error and can't seem to get rid of it regardless of what I try.

[19-01-15 10:57:43.888] Build failed. Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65 Error output: 
 ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

I've tried tns platform remove ios

I've updated my plugins.

I also get these cli warnings before it fails:

```
(CLI) 1) Target 'class2tns' has copy command from ...
```

and

```
(CLI) warning: duplicate output file
```

for a number of files.

My Android version builds ok.

Comment: have you tried to run `tns doctor`?
Exit code 65 is pretty generic for xcode and does not tell much :(

Comment: tns doctor reports no issues:

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exit code from Xcode (65) and the warning of duplicate output file.

After along time of research the following steps are required because an update of a nativescript npm package.

```
rm -Rf platform/ios
rm -Rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
pod repo update # important to execute this command in the project dir
tns build ios
```

Comment: @zarax Did you do an update of the main nativescript packages? Or what changes had you make? At the moment i still use the version 6.3.x and have no app updated to 6.4.x

Comment: I solved this issue. I had an old version of tns-core-modules. After updating its version, I was able to build. Thanks